# extract data from nested parenthesis?

Tags: python

I have a string:

```
test_string = 'RGBA(30(25VARGHK_65FVDFKDGV_10FVDSSLBA)_10UJN(85VOEZSR_5VAVUSR_10SQMCFE)_20BBLRG(SSLCN)_10UDSCT(80EDYFIH_10VAP_10SNE)_30EDU(50EDFva_50VAP)_10EDP(50EDFva_50SNE))'
```

I need to extract the data from the string and the final result should look like that:

```
RGBA,
30TCH:25VARGHK, 65FVDFKDGV, 10FVDSSLBA,
10UJN:85VOEZSR, 5VAVUSR, 5SQMCFE
....
```

and so on..

I thought using regex but it is not good solution here..

Comment: Regex will work if you know the pattern of the data. Or you can use a stack and and push/pop data when you reach each parenthesis...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex will work fine. After you remove the outer `I()`, you have a many sets of "`prefix`" followed by a `(group_of_data)`

If you don't want trailing commas, try this

```
import re

regex = r"[^(]+\([^)]+\)"

s = 'RGBA(30(25VARGHK_65FVDFKDGV_10FVDSSLBA)_10UJN(85VOEZSR_5VAVUSR_10SQMCFE)_20BBLRG(SSLCN)_10UDSCT(80EDYFIH_10VAP_10SNE)_30EDU(50EDFva_50VAP)_10EDP(50EDFva_50SNE))'


first_start = s.index('(')
print(s[:first_start])

matches = re.finditer(regex, s[first_start+1:-1], re.MULTILINE)

for _, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
  g = match.group().lstrip('_')
  data_start = g.index('(')
  prefix = g[:data_start]
  data = ', '.join(g[data_start + 1:-1].split('_'))
  print(f'{prefix}:{data}')
```

Output

```
RGBA
30:25VARGHK, 65FVDFKDGV, 10FVDSSLBA,
10UJN:85VOEZSR, 5VAVUSR, 10SQMCFE
20BBLRG:SSLCN
10UDSCT:80EDYFIH, 10VAP, 10SNE
30EDU:50EDFva, 50VAP
10EDP:50EDFva, 50SNE
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to get you (almost) there -

```py
[_.replace("(", ": ").replace("_", ", ") for _ in re.split(r"\)_", test_string)]
```

**Output**

```
['RGBA: 30TCH: 25VARGHK, 65FVDFKDGV, 10FVDSSLBA',
 '10UJN: 85VOEZSR, 5VAVUSR, 10SQMCFE
 '20BBLRG:SSLCN',
 '10UDSCT:80EDYFIH, 10VAP, 10SNE
 '30EDU:50EDF, 50VPC',
 '10EDP:50EDF, 50SNELP))']
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we may need a little more clarification on the logic.  It looks like `(` should translate into a `:`, but not every time.  Here is my crack at it using regexes.  This might not be exactly what you are looking for, but should be pretty close:

```
import re

def main():
    test_string = 'RGBA(30(25VARGHK_65FVDFKDGV_10FVDSSLBA)_10UJN(85VOEZSR_5VAVUSR_10SQMCFE)_20BBLRG(SSLCN)_10UDSCT(80EDYFIH_10VAP_10SNE)_30EDURKA(50EDFL_50VAP)_10EDPJ(50EDFV_50SNOL))'    
    test_string = re.sub("\)_", ",\n", test_string)
    test_string = re.sub("_", ",", test_string)
    test_string = re.sub("\(", ":", test_string)
    test_string = re.sub("\)\)", "", test_string)

    print(test_string)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

results:

```
RGBA:30:25VARGHK,65FVDFKDGV,10FVDSSLBA,
10UJN:85VOEZSR,5VAVUSR,10SQMCFE,
20BBLRG:SSLCN,
10UDSCT:85EDYFIH,5VAPOR,10SQMCFE,
30EDURKA:70EDFL,30VAPOR,
10EDPJ:50EDFV,50SNOL
```

Pretty much just a series of regexes.  Note that by using `re.sub` like this in an order, you clean the string as you go.  You could certainly just fiddle the beginning of the string to change the first `:` to a `,\n` but I'm not sure if the data you are getting in is always the same.